# I added accounts to my Elementary email client. Client does not show email content

Tags: pantheon-mail

The account routes through a local bridge service that decrypts/encrypts protonmail messages. Following protonmail's instructions, I added an account for my primary email

The account routes through a local bridge service that decrypts/encrypts protonmail messages. Following protonmail's instructions, I added an account for my primary email address account with protonmail, to the bridge. Then I pointed the email client's IMAP and SMTP to the local port 127.0.0.1 to ports 1143 and 1025 respectively, for a given email address (robert.withers@pm.me) and I used the bridge generated password to access those services on the bridge. This is correct setup for the Protonmail Bridge.

Unfortunately, I am able to get a list of existing emails for a selected folder until several minutes pass and I am still unable to see the content of a selected email.